# iOS 3.1.2 [UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:] creates infinite recursion

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have some code that works fine on my iPod Touch running some 4.0-series iOS as well as the simulator that comes with the iOS SDK 4.1.  But when I call [UIViewController dismissModalViewController:] on an iPhone 2 running iOS 3.1.2 it get an infinite recursion, eventually crashing.

I have a view controller that opens a table view where the user selects a document to open.  Upon selecting a document my table view controller's delegate calls the parent view controllers dismissModalViewController method.  I think it is because I'm closing the view controller whose code is running that causes this.

dismissModalViewController is documented to be available in iOS 2.0 and later.

How can I close the UIViewController that's open from its own code?

Comment: post a snippet of the infinite recursion call stack

Comment: coneybeare, I thought it would help to call [NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread: withObject: waitUntilDone:] but it didn't.

Comment: #6662 0x30bf8b18 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
#6663 0x30bf8b18 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
#6664 0x30bf8bf0 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:]
#6665 0x30bf8688 in -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
#6666 0x30c03868 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) insertSubview:atIndex:]
#6667 0x30ce076c in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:]

Comment: To clarify, I am attempting to dismiss the table view after the user has tapped a row.  My function to dismiss is called from a subroutine of the table view's delegate function - tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: It seems to me that deleting the table view from a subroutine of the table view's delegate is what causes the infinite recursion.

Comment: iPhone 2? You mean original iPhone or iPhone 3G?

Answer (score 0):

I figured my problem might be heap corruption from some previous code. A way to debug that is to comment off snippets of previous code to see whether the bug would go away or come back. Almost immediately I found that I was calling dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: on the current view controller's parent controller.  Why that works in iOS 4.x I have no idea.  The problem I face is that I have two modal dialogs that I need to close simultaneously, which I cannot get working, but that is a different question.